# HEX() function in python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, binary, uuid

I stored uuid4 without dashes using native UNHEX() as binary in MySQL and use native HEX() function to retrieve the uuid4.

Example:

```
UUID4: UNHEX("7D96F13AC8394EF5A60E8252B70FC179")
BINARY IN MySQL: }éŽ:·9NŠÙ ýRÈ ¾y
UUID4: HEX(UUID4Column)
```

This works fine to store and retrieve using its functions HEX() and UNHEX().

However, by using ORM sqlalchemy and declare UUID4Column as LargeBinary(16), the return value become `b'}\x96\xf1:\xc89N\xf5\xa6\x0e\x82R\xb7\x0f\xc1y'`

How can convert this bytes to `7D96F13AC8394EF5A60E8252B70FC179`in python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any imports:

You can use [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) with `'X'` to get the hexadecimal representation of the integer:

```
s = b'}\x96\xf1:\xc89N\xf5\xa6\x0e\x82R\xb7\x0f\xc1y'

nicer = f"{(int.from_bytes(s,byteorder='big')):X}"
print(nicer)
```

prints:

```
7D96F13AC8394EF5A60E8252B70FC179
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [binascii.hexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> bs = b'}\x96\xf1:\xc89N\xf5\xa6\x0e\x82R\xb7\x0f\xc1y'
>>> binascii.hexlify(bs)
b'7d96f13ac8394ef5a60e8252b70fc179'

>>> # for str result
>>> binascii.hexlify(bs).decode('ascii')
'7d96f13ac8394ef5a60e8252b70fc179'
```

Comment: hi, thanks for quick ans! Any alternative way to achieve without import binascii module?

Comment: Patrick's answer shows a way to do this without importing binascii.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
>>> print(b'}\x96\xf1:\xc89N\xf5\xa6\x0e\x82R\xb7\x0f\xc1y'.hex())
7d96f13ac8394ef5a60e8252b70fc179
```

Just pass your byte data in a variable or so and `.hex()` it for your answer.
Like this:

```
byte_data = b'}\x96\xf1:\xc89N\xf5\xa6\x0e\x82R\xb7\x0f\xc1y'
print(byte_data.hex())
```